# Ember-ace not works on clear ember project with ember-infinity installs as dependency

Tags: ember.js

Can someone explain why ?
I have no warnings in console. So, i need ember-infinity for my project, but don't know how to force to work ember-infinity with ember-ace.

Using ember-infinity: 2.3.0 and ember-ace: 3.0.0.
Ember-cli version: 4.10.0

To reproduce my situation you need to follow this instruction, so:

1. `npm install -g ember-cli`
2. `ember new ember-quickstart --lang en and add`
3. `yarn add ember-ace`, `yarn add ace-builds` and `yarn add ember-infinity` to install packages. [ember-ace](https://github.com/dfreeman/ember-ace) [ace-builds](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds) [ember-infinity](https://github.com/ember-infinity/ember-infinity)
4. add to template example for ember-ace:

   ```
   <AceEditor
    @value={{<p>test</p>}}
    @options={{hash
    minLines=5
    maxLines=20
    theme='ace/theme/chaos'
    mode='ace/mode/css'
   ```

   }}
   />
5. So the ember-ace the editor will not be shown and there will be no errors in the console.

if I remove ember infinity from the project, then everything is ok

Comment: Hello!
can you provide links to these libraries? (I'm not familiar with these) or a reproduction of the app you're working with? additionally, what do you mean by "not working"? is there an error? is some behavior unexpected? any detail you can provide is immensely helpful! thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ember-infinity looks a smidge unmaintained -- they don't have explicit support for Ember v4+

Maybe https://github.com/html-next/vertical-collection will suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Yes, I'm too thinking that ember-infinity is no longer supported. So, that's why ember-ace is not working. Will try another package.